# Python replace all characters in a string except for 3 characters with underscores

Tags: python, replace, char

I'm working on a simple hangman app and I am trying to replace all the chars but three, in a word users have to guess, with underscores randomly.

So for example: `America` to `A_M___C_`

I have most of it down, but my code sometimes leaves more than 3 characters unconverted to underscores. Here is my code:

```
topics = {
    "movie": ["Star-Trek", "Shang-Chi"],
    "place": ["PARIS", "AMERICA", "ENGLAND"]
} 
topic = random.choice(["movie", "place"])
solution = random.choice(topics[topic])
question = ""
length = len(solution)
underscores = length - 3

for char in solution:
    for i in range(underscores):
        add = question + random.choice([char, "_"])
        question = question + add
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that we don't have to guess what `topics` and `self.topic` are and how they were initialized.

Comment: @tripleee ok I added them in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code. First of all the inner loop will restart for every character but that's not what you want. You want to put x underscores. Secondly, you only need to add your random choice, and not the while question. So, below a working program:

```
# get len(solution) - 3 unique numbers 
indices = random.sample(range(len(solution)), len(solution) - 3) 
question = list(solution) # convert to a list so we can index
for i in indices:
    question[i] = "_" # change them to underscores

question = "".join(question) # convert to list to a string
```

The reasen your solution (and my previous solution) don't work is because the number of not underscores isn't limited. So you could keep a counter with the number of not underscores, and when that's equal to 3, only replace characters by underscores like this, but keep in mind you would still need to track the number of underscores. So this solution is better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i added in what solution is, however your code yielded about the same result as mine

Comment: could you specify when

Comment: like `question` could have more than 3 letters, like when I just ran it I got Sha_g_Chi as a result

Comment: Yes, you're right, i edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rehash your problem statement:

Given a string of unspecified length with more than three different characters, you want to keep three of these unique characters, and replace all the others.

Notice that the string could contain duplicates, so if your string is "abracadabra" and `a` is one of the letters you want to keep, that already gets you `a__a_a_a__a`.

```
import random


topics = {
    "movie": ["Star-Trek", "Shang-Chi"],
    "place": ["PARIS", "AMERICA", "ENGLAND"]
} 
topic = random.choice(["movie", "place"])
solution = random.choice(topics[topic])

characters = set(solution)
keep = random.sample(list(characters), 3)

question = solution
for char in characters.difference(keep):
    question = question.replace(char, '_')
```

`set(solution)` produces a `set` of the unique characters in the string, and `random_sample(list(characters), 3)` picks three of them (forcing the `set` back to a `list` is required to avoid a deprecation warning in Python >= 3.9).  We then use the `set.difference()` to loop over the remaining unique characters, and replace all occurrences of them with underscores.

Your attempt doesn't normalize characters to upper or lower case; I would assume this is something you would actually want to do, but then probably normalize the questions to upper case already in the source.  I'm leaving this as an excercise; this code simply regards `a` and `A` as different characters.

Comment: Although the examples would work, the word Banana would not work. This may be irrelevant but it's just something to note. Also, `DeprecationWarning: Sampling from a set deprecated
since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version.` But this is easely solvable by taking a list from this set

Comment: Thanks. The note about more than 3 distinct characters was meant to guard against the _banana_ problem but perhaps it could be clarified. I'll update to use a list for sampling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one function that takes in a string and optional number to save letters, so 3 will save 3 letters, 5 will save 5 letters. There is no error check to see if save_letters is larger than the word and so forth. The code is supposed to show you exactly what is happening, not to be a clever one liner.

```
import random 
def change_word(word, save_letters = 3):
    length = len(word)
    randies = []
    ret = ""
    while len(randies) < save_letters:
        x = random.randint(0,length - 1)
        if not x in randies:
            randies.append(x)
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if i in randies:
            ret += word[i]
            continue
        ret += "_"

    return ret
```